# Voldemort run time error

Tags: java, voldemort

I'm trying to run the Client Example which can be found with the Voldemort download.

My Path Location:
/home/voldemart/voldemort-1.3.0/clientjava

I compiled the code

javac -classpath ../dist/voldemort-1.3.0.jar ClientVoldemort.java

No errors appeared. But when I try to run the code as follows:

```
java -classpath ../dist/voldemort-1.3.0.jar ClientVoldemort
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ClientVoldemort
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ClientVoldemort
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:276)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:251)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:319)

ClientExample code Given below.

package voldemort.examples;
import voldemort.client.ClientConfig;
import voldemort.client.SocketStoreClientFactory;
import voldemort.client.StoreClient;
import voldemort.client.StoreClientFactory;
import voldemort.versioning.Versioned;
public class ClientExample {
public static void main(String[] args) {
String bootstrapUrl = "tcp://localhost:6666";
StoreClientFactory factory = new SocketStoreClientFactory(new ClientConfig().setBootstrapUrls(bootstrapUrl));
StoreClient<String, String> client = factory.getStoreClient("my_store_name");
Versioned<String> version = client.get("some_key");
version.setObject("new_value");
client.put("some_key", version);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears the JVM is not finding the class at the expected location, i.e. `voldemort/examples` relative to the current directory

There are a few adjustments required

- Add the current directory to the classpath,
- Qualify the class as `voldemort.examples.ClientVoldemort`

Move the class to `voldemort/examples` and use

Compile & run commands:

```
javac -cp ../dist/voldemort-1.3.0.jar voldemort/examples/*.java
java -cp ../dist/voldemort-1.3.0.jar:. voldemort.examples.ClientVoldemort
```

Note: When the `-classpath` or `-cp` flags are used, the current directory is not automatically included in the classpath (in contrast to not using either of these flags)

Answer (score 0):

NoClassDefFoundError means that the file existed during compile time but could not be found at run time, since the classpath was not set correctly. One way to check this out is to open your .jar file in a winzip it will show you all the files that exists in the jar. You will mostly see that your class is missing in the jar when you get this exception